# Add moving average value in last row using array in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

'The code should add the moving average to last row using array. The Prices to be use to average are in range "E6:E7555". The values will be written in "G7555". There is an existing moving average values in range "G6:G7554". Need help from Excel VBA expert to correct the codes which I think in step 1 and 2 below.

```
Options Explicit

Sub Add_MovingAverage_to_LastRows()

    Dim maArray As Variant
    Dim runSum, ma() As Double
    Dim i, lRow, iPeriod, iCol As Long
    
    iPeriod = 7

    'set last row and reference range to calculate
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
      lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row                                  'Row "7555"
      maArray = .Range(.Cells(lRow - (iPeriod -1), 5), .Cells(lRow, 5)).Value2    'Column "E"
    End With

    'set the lower and upper bound
    ReDim ma1(lRow - (iPeriod - 1) To lRow, 1 To 1)
    
    'step 1 calculate the SUM for last row, sum (row "7549" to row "7555")
    runSum = 0
    For i = lRow - (iPeriod-1) To lRow
      runSum1 = runSum1 + maArray(i, 1)
    Next

    'step 2 calculate the AVERAGE for last row, average (row "7549" to row "7555")
    ma(1, 1) = runSum / iPeriod
    
    'write the values to worksheet
    iCol = 7    'Column "G"
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range(.Cells(lRow, iCol), .Cells(lRow, iCol)).Value2 = ma
    End With
    
    Erase maArray: Erase ma 
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: HI @cybernetic.nomad, i want to add the 7-period moving average of the Close Price (from range "E6:E7555") in last row using array (not using worksheet function) to be faster, in this instance in  Cell G7555 but this should be dynamic. I think i messed up in steps 1 and 2 in the code comments.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to stick to a Formula on G column instead of VBA. If you add this formula on G6 and drag down: (Test it out on column H next to it)

`=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("E"&IF(ROW()-6<6,6,ROW()-6)&":"&"E"&ROW()))`

The IF Statement is to not break the formula on the first few rows of the file.

It will always grab the last 6+current row of values in Column E to calculate the Average.

Edit: Summary

`="E"&IF(ROW()-6<6,6,ROW()-6)&":"&"E"&ROW()` if you paste this into I6 and drag down you can see how it is just graving the 7 Cell Range you are looking for. When you enclose this into `INDIRECT` then you can use this inside other formulas as a "literal range" as in my answer above with `AVERAGE`.

Edit 2: VBA Code to automatically drag/fill down formula.

```
Sub UpdateFill()
    Dim lRow As Long, lFormulaRow
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        lDateRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lFormulaRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
        If lDateRow > lFormulaRow Then
            .Range("G" & lFormulaRow & ":G" & lDateRow).FillDown
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I prefer without formula since it will add weight and will slow the process. This code will run to 2000 .xlsb files and each file contains thousands of data. I have a VBA codes that are based in RANGE and runs about 3 hours. I wanted to reduce the runtime, that is why I am on the process of converting all the codes from RANGE to ARRAY.

Comment: I understand your concern, however the formula above helps to only care/look for 7 rows. I just tested this out on a file with 274000 rows of true production data and updated in just 1 second.
If the formula is of a true concern you may want the VBA code to: 1. Remove all Values from Column G, 2. Apply formula on G6, 3. Use Range.FillDown to copy formula down to the last row and 4. Use Range.PasteSpecial xValues to remove the formula and keep values. An array could add additional work where a much simpler solution is available.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But according to most experts, in order to optimize the speed of VBA  is to limit the interaction with the worksheet i.e. do all reading, calculation and store in array then at the end write all at once to worksheet. In addition, avoid using worksheet function..

Comment: There is a balance between "limit interaction with the worksheet" and "use the least VBA code that you can" in order to Optimize the speed of VBA. Assuming you use the formula I mention, the VBA code would be reduced to 3 rows of actual code. Updated in my answer. From your For Loop to add an Array then divide, then insert value into the Cell to a single drag down of 1 cell. I can argue that in speed it may be faster.

Comment: Ricardo many thanks, but not sure if possible if this can be done using array and preferably not using range and not to start from the very top down to last row i.e. the requirement is only last row since this will be updated daily. I already have a RANGE and ARRAY VBA code that run from top to last row, I am actually looking for a version of ARRAY VBA code that will calculate only the last row...